# Can't get Azure KeyVault configuration provider to work

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-keyvault

I was trying to setup Azure KeyVault configuration provider in a .Net Core Console Application.
I've followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x) documentation to do so.

But it does not fetch the secret. I'm able to fetch it using the KeyVaultClient though.

Here's the complete code:

```
class Program
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        var secretUri = $"{Configuration["Vault"]}secrets/testSecret/4438b47c28cc413f9434bcb2d3c7d7ca";

        var keyVault = new KeyVaultClient(async (string authority, string resource, string scope) => {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            var credential = new ClientCredential(Configuration["ClientId"], Configuration["ClientSecret"]);
            var token = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential);

            return token.AccessToken;
        });

        var result1 = keyVault.GetSecretAsync(secretUri).Result.Value;

        builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
            Configuration["Vault"],
            Configuration["ClientId"],
            Configuration["ClientSecret"]);

        var result2 = Configuration["testSecret"];
    }
}
```

`result1` gets the value from the keyvault, but `result2` is `null`.

Not sure what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

I also follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x) that you mentioned. I could get the value if I re-build the builder after we add the keyVault.

```
 builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
            Configuration["Vault"],
            Configuration["ClientId"],
            Configuration["ClientSecret"]);
Configuration = builder.Build();
var result2 = Configuration["testSecret"];
```

**Test result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! re-building did it. :)